# Patentablity of Simplex noise

Tags: patentability, us6867776

[Simplex noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_noise) is patented in [US6867776 B2](http://www.google.com/patents/US6867776) but it was published in Mar 15, 2005 before [Alice Corp. v. CLS Bank International](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_Corp._v._CLS_Bank_International) in 2014 where the US Supreme Court said that merely saying apply it with a computer is not enough to confer patent eligibility. Does this mean that the Simplex noise patent is invalid? The patent (IMHO) just says apply the formula with a computer for generating images and display them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alice is more complicated than that, and the fallout of the ruling is just starting. Some issues are: Can you do it in your head? Is what the computer is doing something old or something new? Until a court of the USPTO takes some action, all granted patents stand in force.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Is it to bad that the patent system is very unclear about this.